# Java update the scheduletime for a loop

Tags: java

I am making this program where i let the person set up a workout in form of running intervals. I have made a timer that i want to work as the "sleeptime" for the loop but for some reason it only gets the first value almost as if when you set the value it locks to that value. The values of the timelapse are set up in a menu of JSliders.

```
public static ArrayList <JSlider> sliderList = new ArrayList<JSlider>();
public static ArrayList <Integer> timeLapse = new ArrayList<Integer>();


buttonList.get(2).addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            if(sliderList.size() > 1){
            for(int i = 0; i < sliderList.size();i++){
                timeLapse.add(sliderList.get(i).getValue());
            }
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
            { 
                public void run() {
                    if(currentColor == Color.red){

                        currentColor = Color.green;
                        timeLapseCounter++;
                        music(startSound);

                        green.setIcon(new ImageIcon(("green.jpg")));
                        green.setBounds(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
                        frame.getContentPane().remove(red);
                        frame.getContentPane().add(green);

                        game.repaint();
                    }else if(currentColor == Color.green){
                        currentColor = Color.red;
                        timeLapseCounter++;
                        red.setIcon(new ImageIcon("red.jpg"));
                        red.setBounds(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
                        frame.getContentPane().remove(green);
                        frame.getContentPane().add(red);

                        music(stopSound);
                        game.repaint();
                    }
                } 
            },0, timeLapse.get(timeLapseCounter));
            timeLapse.clear();
        }


        }
    });
```

Comment: `timeLapse.clear();` - what do you think this does?

Comment: I thought as i want to be able to rerun the  program later on. As i have already gotten the "data" that i need for the loop. I clear the arraylist so that it can get filled with new when the user gets back to the menusystem

Comment: OK, but what you are doing is clear it after the first Task executes. So there is only one task being scheduled with the first timeLaps value, then the List is cleared. You'd rather give a copy to the Timertask and don't schedule it recurring, but at the end of the timertask schedule the next one with the next value from the list.